# Unable to toggle hitboxes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

Here's the basics:
I'm on a Windows 10, playing on Minecraft Java Edition, 1.16.1
When I press any other Debug command (That consists of Fn + F3) EXCEPT for Fn + F3 + B, it works.
Pressing Fn + F3 + B does... nothing.

The B key works perfectly fine when I'm typing, I looked around everywhere on how to enable hitboxes, and everyone just said, "Press F3 + B". There IS one person unable to turn on hitboxes [here](https://www.planetminecraft.com/forums/help/javaedition/hitboxes-won-show-with-help-461047/), but I didn't find any helpful pointers.

Does anyone have the same problem, and what are the possible reasons for this problem?
I can give more information if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: It may have to do with anti-ghosting. That is, when you press multiple keys, it may not be registering all of them being pressed. I read about that and some say it's because of the keyboard but there's this solution that may help:
https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/multiple-key-presses-at-once-not-registering.2597665/

Comment: Can you check your settings and see if you have reduced debug info on? If yes, try turning it off and see if hitboxes show up.

Comment: @54D I had it off originally, but either setting doesn't work

Comment: Does the traditional "install it again" method work? Is this issue isolated to only one specific version? (eg. try toggling on hitboxes in 1.8 / 1.13)

Answer (score 2):

Are you holding all 3 keys at the same time? Or maybe you/your settings reprogrammed the shortcuts. Try Fn + F3 + Q to check all the debug shortcuts.

Comment: Yes I am, and no, didn't change anything. When I did F3 + Q, it shows me the debug commands, but F3 + B doesn't work.

Comment: If you are using mods like journeymap, a shortcut/keybind "B" is added. This may be the reason. Try pressing just "B" to see what happens. I'm using journeymap so it doesn't work for me too.

Comment: I never use mods Yuta, so I think the problem is somewhere else